# SQL PIVOT Table not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table as follows

```
SELECT AttributeDataID, [0],[1],[10],[131],[132],[133],[134],[135],[136],[137],[138],[139],[140],[141],[142],[143],[144],[145],[146],[147],[148],[149],[150],[151],[152],[153],[154],[155],[157],[158],[159],[160],[161],[162],[163],[164],[165],[166],[167],[168],[169],[170],[171],[172],[173],[174],[175],[176],[177],[178],[179],[180],[181],[182],[183],[184],[185],[186],[187],[188],[189],[190],[191],[192],[193],[194],[195],[196],[197],[198],[199],[2],[200],[202],[203],[204],[205],[206],[207],[208],[209],[211],[212],[213],[214],[215],[216],[217],[218],[219],[220],[221],[222],[223],[224],[225],[226],[227],[228],[229],[230],[231],[232],[233],[234],[235],[236],[237],[238],[239],[240],[241],[242],[243],[244],[245],[246],[247],[248],[250],[251],[252],[3],[4],[43],[44],[5],[6],[7],[8],[85],[86],[9]
FROM (SELECT t2.AttributeDataID, t1.AttributeName, t2.DataValue 
      FROM AttributeDefinitions As t1 JOIN AttributeDatum AS t2 ON t1.AttributeDefinitionId = t2.AttributeDefinitionRef) 
p PIVOT (max(t2.DataValue) FOR t1.AttributeName IN 
     ([0],[1],[10],[131],[132],[133],[134],[135],[136],[137],[138],[139],[140],[141],[142],[143],[144],[145],[146],[147],[148],[149],[150],[151],[152],[153],[154],[155],[157],[158],[159],[160],[161],[162],[163],[164],[165],[166],[167],[168],[169],[170],[171],[172],[173],[174],[175],[176],[177],[178],[179],[180],[181],[182],[183],[184],[185],[186],[187],[188],[189],[190],[191],[192],[193],[194],[195],[196],[197],[198],[199],[2],[200],[202],[203],[204],[205],[206],[207],[208],[209],[211],[212],[213],[214],[215],[216],[217],[218],[219],[220],[221],[222],[223],[224],[225],[226],[227],[228],[229],[230],[231],[232],[233],[234],[235],[236],[237],[238],[239],[240],[241],[242],[243],[244],[245],[246],[247],[248],[250],[251],[252],[3],[4],[43],[44],[5],[6],[7],[8],[85],[86],[9]) 
      AS pvt ORDER BY AttributeDataID;
```

But the following message is being returned. Can anyone please help?

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Martin. I have just discovered this but now it says

Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
The column prefix 't2' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
The column prefix 't1' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: I just needed to remove the t1. and t2. as these were self referenced and not referring to the source tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the aliases from your inner query in the `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT AttributeDataID, [0],[1],[10],[131],[132],[133],[134],[135],[136],[137],[138],[139],[140],[141],[142],[143],[144],[145],[146],[147],[148],[149],[150],[151],[152],[153],[154],[155],[157],[158],[159],[160],[161],[162],[163],[164],[165],[166],[167],[168],[169],[170],[171],[172],[173],[174],[175],[176],[177],[178],[179],[180],[181],[182],[183],[184],[185],[186],[187],[188],[189],[190],[191],[192],[193],[194],[195],[196],[197],[198],[199],[2],[200],[202],[203],[204],[205],[206],[207],[208],[209],[211],[212],[213],[214],[215],[216],[217],[218],[219],[220],[221],[222],[223],[224],[225],[226],[227],[228],[229],[230],[231],[232],[233],[234],[235],[236],[237],[238],[239],[240],[241],[242],[243],[244],[245],[246],[247],[248],[250],[251],[252],[3],[4],[43],[44],[5],[6],[7],[8],[85],[86],[9]
FROM 
(
  SELECT t2.AttributeDataID, t1.AttributeName, t2.DataValue 
  FROM AttributeDefinitions As t1 
  JOIN AttributeDatum AS t2 
    ON t1.AttributeDefinitionId = t2.AttributeDefinitionRef
)p 
PIVOT 
(
  max(DataValue) -- < no inner query alias here
  FOR AttributeName IN  -- < no inner query alias here
     ([0],[1],[10],[131],[132],[133],[134],[135],[136],[137],[138],[139],[140],[141],[142],[143],[144],[145],[146],[147],[148],[149],[150],[151],[152],[153],[154],[155],[157],[158],[159],[160],[161],[162],[163],[164],[165],[166],[167],[168],[169],[170],[171],[172],[173],[174],[175],[176],[177],[178],[179],[180],[181],[182],[183],[184],[185],[186],[187],[188],[189],[190],[191],[192],[193],[194],[195],[196],[197],[198],[199],[2],[200],[202],[203],[204],[205],[206],[207],[208],[209],[211],[212],[213],[214],[215],[216],[217],[218],[219],[220],[221],[222],[223],[224],[225],[226],[227],[228],[229],[230],[231],[232],[233],[234],[235],[236],[237],[238],[239],[240],[241],[242],[243],[244],[245],[246],[247],[248],[250],[251],[252],[3],[4],[43],[44],[5],[6],[7],[8],[85],[86],[9]) 
) AS pvt 
ORDER BY AttributeDataID;
```

Just to make it clear: you *can* prefix the columns referenced by `PIVOT` with table aliases. It's just that in your case it could only be the `p` alias, i.e.

```
…
max(p.DataValue)
FOR p.AttributeName IN
…
```

because the columns being pivoted are known to the `PIVOT` as columns of the `p` subselect rather than columns of `t1` or `t2`.